# How to Authenticate Google Cloud Services on PyGSheets deployed in Web Server (Heroku)

Tags: python, heroku, google-api, google-oauth, pygsheets

Hi I want to use pygsheets to log events to my google spreadsheet. This will be scheduled thus deployed in a web server particularly Heroku.

I am only using these lines to authenticate:

```
import pygsheets
gc = pygsheets.authorize()
```

Running locally, it works fine since I have to copy the authentication link and paste the code afterwards. But what if it's on Heroku.

I get these logs on Heroku:

```
2018-09-06T03:48:25.234859+00:00 app[web.1]: Your browser has been opened to visit:
2018-09-06T03:48:25.234861+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-09-06T03:48:25.234870+00:00 app[web.1]:     https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=XXXXXXXX-iXXXXXXXXXXXXXX.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fspreadsheets+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive&access_type=offline&response_type=code
2018-09-06T03:48:25.234872+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

I tried copying the link, it asked me to login. The endpoint was this link:

```
http://localhost:8080/?code=4/UgAXXXX6cdAt5Cnuj7yvTeoUgtfWyCvi8e2Rw-cxWiBVhACvom1qVgln0OfE1mOz3zENCXXXXvsOU4daXxI#
```

I am not sure why it is localhost.

I also research about authenticating Google Cloud Services for Heroku and bumped into this [LINK](https://medium.com/@naz_islam/how-to-authenticate-google-cloud-services-on-heroku-for-node-js-app-dda9f4eda798).

I created another Service Account Key.

and wrote on my CLI:

```
$ heroku config:set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=‘keyFile.json’
```

But it still doesn't solve the problem.
I still get these logs:

```
2018-09-06T03:55:59.083071+00:00 app[web.1]: Your browser has been opened to visit:
2018-09-06T03:55:59.083072+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-09-06T03:55:59.083075+00:00 app[web.1]:     https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=XXXXX-isqd84kjnfu7o6XXXX6p79crvco2ms.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8090%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fspreadsheets+https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive&access_type=offline&response_type=code
2018-09-06T03:55:59.083076+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-09-06T03:55:59.083078+00:00 app[web.1]: If your browser is on a different machine then exit and re-run this
2018-09-06T03:55:59.083080+00:00 app[web.1]: application with the command-line parameter
2018-09-06T03:55:59.083082+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2018-09-06T03:55:59.083084+00:00 app[web.1]:   --noauth_local_webserver
```

My directory BTW,

```
- app.py
- client_secret.json
- keyfile.json
- Procfile
- requirements.txt
```

More:
I also tried using:

```
gc = pygsheets.authorize(service_account_file='keyfile.json')
```

But the same output on Heroku.

Comment: did you try service account?

Comment: my keyfile.json is the service account   "type": "service_account",

Comment: Hey you go to https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials is the credential you created a service account or Oauth 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

I think your issue is you are using different version of pygsheets on your local and on Heroku. On your local you are using master version. but on the server you are using 1.1.4, which needs to set a `outh_nonlocal` param to enable oauthorization in server. also the param for the service_account was changed from `service_file`.

Comment: Still no resolve :(, https://github.com/nithinmurali/pygsheets/issues/277